# Select 3 random Words (records) - one of each letter count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with lots of words and also a field that holds the number of letters for each word.

EDIT: The example data set below is just showing the table layout - there are 65,000 rows of all combinations of lengths.

```
word_id,word,letter_count
54908,swanage,7
37338,natured,7
61637,untwisting,10
```

I am trying to select three random words making sure there is one that is 4 letters, one that is 7 letters and one that is 10.

My SQL query is below.

```
SELECT * FROM password
WHERE letter_count = 4 OR letter_count = 7 OR letter_count = 10
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3
```

The above will return 3 random records but may have any combination of 4, 7 or 10 letters.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

John

Comment: It's not possible. There are no 4 letter words in the data set (although I can think of a few)

Comment: @Strawberry lol

Comment: Sorry, the example data set was just showing the table layout - there are 65,000 rows of all cominations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(word_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,word VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'swanage'),
(2,'natured'),
(3,'untwisting'),
(4,'four'),
(5,'five'),
(6,'fifteen'),
(7,'blacksmith');


SELECT * 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(word) = 4 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ) x
 UNION
     ( SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(word) = 7 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ) 
 UNION
     ( SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(word) = 10 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) ;

+---------+------------+
| word_id | word       |
+---------+------------+
|       4 | four       |
|       1 | swanage    |
|       3 | untwisting |
+---------+------------+
```

Comment: I don't know why this has been downvoted. This is the correct approach, one randomly found four-letter word, one randomly found seven-letter word, and one randomly found ten-letter word. It should better be `UNION ALL`, though; there are no duplicates to remove.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Haters gonna hate ;-)

Comment: I agree @ThorstenKettner - works a treat and was surprised to see it down voted.